# Android - Disable softkeybaord from poping up

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

I am programming for a `Pidion` device that is running `Android 2.3.7 (Gingerbread)`. The `Pidion` comes with a built in `keyboard` and I would like to disable the `softkeyboard` from opening.

[image: Pidion]

What is the best way to disable softkeyboard?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextReference)).setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

inside Activity you can do this:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

or inside Fragment you can just use

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: this does not seem to be working, I added it to my main activity and the fragment